# Is there a grep command that allows me to grep multiple folders and copy them using a text file containing the file names

Tags: linux, bash, unix

So I have a text file containing the names of ~1000 folder names, and a directory with around ~30,000 folders. What I need to do is to find a bash command that will read the text file for the folder names, and grep those folders from the directory and copy them to a new destination. Is this at all possible?

I am new to coding, my apologies if this isn't worded well.

Comment: What do you mean by _grep those folders_?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps that was unclear. I need to grab the folders whose names match the list of names in the text file and copy them to a new location. So my 'grep' I meant just to collectively grab them to be able to be copied somewhere

Comment: Please show a short example how the contents of your file looks like. Does it contain absolute or relative paths?

Comment: Contents of files I am trying to copy or the textfile list? Also I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean by absolute vs relative paths

Answer (score 1):

you can use a bash scrit like this one:

```
fileList=$(cat nameFIle)
srcDir="/home/ex/src"
destDir="/home/ex/dest"

for name in fileList 
do
  cp -r "${srcDir}/${name}" "${destDir}"/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible - and you don't even need grep. Assuming your text file has one file per line.

```
cp -r `cat filenames.txt` path_to_copy_location/
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I got a missing destination file operand after the path_to_copy_location/ when I tried this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
xargs cp -t /destination/directory < file.of.dirnames
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! I got' cp cannot stat 'filenamefromlist\r' : No such file or directory'. Am I doing something wrong? While does the filename have a \r after it?

Comment: Your text editor is to blame most likely. Change its settings to save the file as a "unix" file. Use `dos2unix` to fix the line endings of the script file and the file containing the folder names..

Comment: I saved the textfile as unix file but for dos2unix, do I use that as a part of the command you suggested?